# Null check is creating problems

Tags: javascript, null

```
let age = prompt('What is your name?');

if(age  != null){
    document.write(`Your name is ${age}`) 
}else{
    document.write("You didn't enter your age");
}
```

Null check isn't working like even when I am leaving it blank it is showing : Your name is

but when i wrote this -

```
let age = prompt('What is your name?');

if(age == null){
    document.write(`Your name is ${age}`) 
}else{
    document.write("You didn't enter your age");
}
```

It is always showing 'You didn't enter your age'

Comment: It's only null if you cancel the prompt. If you submit the prompt but with an empty value, it's an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

Because when you don't enter something, `age` does not contain `null` but an empty string (a string of length 0). You can confirm this by:

```
let age = prompt('What is your name?');
console.log(age); // prints ''
console.log(age.length); // prints 0

if(age  != null){
    document.write(`Your name is ${age}`) 
}else{
    document.write("You didn't enter your age");
}
```

In reality, you just need to do:

```
let age = prompt('What is your name?');

if(age){
    document.write(`Your name is ${age}`) 
}else{
    document.write("You didn't enter your age");
}
```